# What is the correct way to send an array of objects where the value of one of the properties of the object must be a file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to upload an array of objects to the backend, these objects have the following form, `{name: string, date: string, file: File}`. Using the Fetch API what is the correct way to send an array of objects where the value of one of the properties of the object must be a file?

```
async function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const files = Array.from(event.target.file.files);
    const validFiles = getOnlyValidFiles(files);

    if (!files.length || !validFiles.length) {
        console.log("No data to submit");

        return;
    }

    const data = validFiles.map(getFileMeta);
    const response = await fetch("/api/v1/upload/files", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    console.log(json);
}
```

getFileMeta

```
function getFileMeta(file) {
    let [article, date] = file.name.split("_");

    date = date.split(".")[0]; // exclude .pdf

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);

    return {
        article,
        reception,
        file: formData,
    };
}
```

E

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a file via JSON with a content-type of text/json.  You *could* serialize it though I guess which might get you closer, but you'll want to use **FormData** (and append each file and the content to the array).   I guess you could use a Reference Pointer and try to ref the file in the JSON object itself, but I doubt that's actually gonna work (unless you have a way of parsing the JSON object as a JS object on the backend to get that reference back - which I suppose would work?).  Either way you'll want a multipart form content type to send this File.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file